# Angularjs directive link call function in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My directive works fine, but I'd like to use it in `ng-click` However, the function inside link can't be triggered.

http://jsfiddle.net/ovzyro1f/

```
<div ng-app="editer" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
  <div class="parents">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="wrap" sibs>
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      <button ng-click="">click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.editedItem = null;

  $scope.items = [{
    name: "item #1",
    thing: "thing 1"
  }, {
    name: "item #2",
    thing: "thing 2"
  }, {
    name: "item #3",
    thing: "thing 3"
  }];

  $scope.show = false; //ignore this line

}

var editer = angular.module('editer', []);

editer.directive('sibs', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        element.parent().children().addClass('unclicked');
        element.removeClass('unclicked');
      })

      scope.myClick = function() {
        element.parent().children().addClass('unclicked');
        element.removeClass('unclicked');
      }
    },
  }
});
```

I'd like to call the function in ng-click please see this one http://jsfiddle.net/ovzyro1f/2/  to remove sib from `div ng-repeat="item in items" class="wrap"`

```
 <button ng-click="myClick()">click</button>
```

Comment: It works for me. I edited your JSFilddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ovzyro1f/1/

Comment: Yes, it is working but I'd like to call the function in ng-click please see this one http://jsfiddle.net/ovzyro1f/2/ to remove sib from `div ng-repeat="item in items" class="wrap"` thanks

Comment: Why do you want to remove `sibs`?

Comment: I am trying to call the function in `ng-click`, if I only write a function like `$scope.myClick = function()...` it doesn't work. so I had to use `directive`? I am new

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid to manipulate the DOM like we do in jQuery.

In Angular we think differently: it's the data which transforms automatically the DOM when the data changes (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding). Most of the time you never have to make the changes manually.

In doing so, you generally don't need to use the link function. You can have a controller (like in your example) or a directive with a controller (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Finally I just modified a little bit your controller and your template.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="editer" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
  <div class="parents">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="wrap" sibs>
      <span ng-class="{ unclicked: !item.selected }">{{ item.name }}</span>
      <button ng-click="selectItem(item)">click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function myCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.items = [...];

  $scope.selectItem = function (item) {

      // reset all the items
      $scope.items.forEach(function (i) {
          i.selected = false;
      });

      // set the new selected item
      item.selected = true;
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks I know I can do this way, I am trying to traverse all siblings, I have tried this way.

Comment: I edited my answer with some explanations. Hope it will help you. :)